# Image not found --> creates a path that doesn't exists

Tags: 7, uri, media

I'm trying to make a gallery with the Galleria module.
I did everything that the install guide said (module readme) and got the module to work, one time, but then when I went to my front page and back to the gallery I got the following.

[image]

I looked in my field setting and didn't create a sub directory. Then, I checked my "File system" configuration and the public path is said to be sites/default/files.

I have no clue why it needs the other directories or where it gets that path from.

Is there someone who could explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install Galleria, it creates the image style presets it requires, which you can find under **/admin/config/media/image-styles**.

If you view the images, imagecache will create the image types and store them in the file system under the appropriate direcory so they will not have to be re-created. If your file system does not have the correct permissions, the directories and files cannot be created, and the images cannot be found.

Check your logs for error messages (**/admin/reports/dblog**). If this is the case you need to make sure that the directory tree has the correct ownership (usually apache.apache) and the correct read.write permissions (664). If you have access to the server, use the `chown -R apache.apache *` and `chmod -R 664 *` commands to accomplish this.

Once you have verified the permission, galleria should work correctly.

Comment: Hey Triskelion, thx alot for the help. I went and took a look at the image-styles and they werent there. So I followed your advice and checked the log. There weren't any errors, so I looked further. The problem was indeed with the apache. I'm using WAMP server to localy build my website, but I had to restart the apache service before it would add the image-styles. Anyway thx alot.